# jquery acting different local vs production

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-ui slider and for some reason the sliders show up local but not on producton. I cleaned and precompiled the assets several times and I am not getting any errors.  Has anyone see this type of behavior before?

Comment: Could it be caused by a stale browser cache (or stale cdn cache)?

Answer (score 1):

Along with the assets, please check if all CSS files are also uploaded into remote server.

Answer (score 1):

Without having seen your code. Have you made sure the DOM is ready before executing the script? On your local machine, the page may load so fast that the DOM is ready before the script is executed. In the live environment however, there is a risk that the loading is slower and that the DOM isn't ready when the script is executed. In that case the script will fail because it will not find any DOM-elements that match your selector, and it will fail without any JS-errors being thrown.